# Can transfer learning be applied after learning using homomorphic encryption to obfuscate dataset source?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, dataset, transfer-learning

### Context

Suppose one has a public dataset `plant_labels` with:

- Input: plant pictures
- Labels: plant names

And a larger public model: `object` for object recognition with:

- Input: object picturesmodel
- Labels: object names

which has been trained on various public datasets, *except for `plant_labels`*.

### Scenarios

Suppose 2 different scenarios:

1. One applies homomorphic encryption to the `plant_labels` dataset and trains a model `HE_plant_I` on it. Next, one applies transfer learning to improve the larger model `object` with it.
2. One first trains model `plant_II` without homomorphic encryption, then applies transfer learning to towards a `HE_plant_II` model with homomorphic encryption, and then applies transfer learning again from the `HE_plant` model towards the `object` model to improve it.

### Assumptions

I assume either 1 and/or 2 is possible, if this assumption is invalid, feel free to clarify that.

### Question

Assuming either 1 and/or 2 is/are possible, is it possible to do in such a way that others* cannot determine, or prove, on which dataset you have trained the `HE_plant_I` (or `HE_plant_II`?

Others who also have access to all the datasets on which `object` is trained, as well as access to dataset `plant`, (but e.g. not to your random seed used for training).